# Guitar tablature in posts?

Tags: discussion, jtab

Anyone have a good way to show guitar tablature on these site yet? For example, see how this doesn't show up?

```
E|-0-| doesn't show up
B|-x-|
G|-2-|
D|-2-|
A|-1-|
E|-0-|
```

How do we get around this without weird fonts? I've been using html linebreaks: `<br/>`

E|-0-| shows up but looks bad 
B|-x-| 
G|-2-|
D|-2-|
A|-1-|
E|-0-|

Comment: I'm on Chrome.  It shows up when the page loads and then disappears.  The background remains grey though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try it with a `<pre>` block.  This

```
<pre>
E|-0-| doesn't show up
B|-x-|
G|-2-|
D|-2-|
A|-1-|
E|-0-|
</pre>
```

shows as

```
E|-0-| doesn't show up
B|-x-|
G|-2-|
D|-2-|
A|-1-|
E|-0-|
```

The reason indentation doesn't work is because of our jTab plugin.  You can, of course, learn to use jTab's format if you want.

Comment: jTab's format is...?

Comment: http://jtab.tardate.com/ gives you all the info you will need

Comment: I tried both the `%` and `$` methods for tabs and chords, but had no luck getting them to generate on this site. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Turns out is needs to be indented, which makes sense as why I was having this problem to begin with.

Comment: As a reference to others, [here](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6456/how-do-you-play-c7-fast-on-a-guitar/6458#6458) is kevlar's answer where he has now successfully implemented use of jTab (which was the reason for his question here on Meta in the first place).